# Images showing in editor but not in post

Tags: images, wordpress.com-hosting

Images are showing up in the editor, but not in the post. What's weird is that on initial page load, the images flash into existence and then disappear with a broken image icon. Here is an example post:

https://deephollowfarmct.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/where-oh-where-has-the-time-gone/

This site is brand new on Wordpress.com. Everything was imported from an pre-existing self-hosted WordPress site (I used the built-in export tool to generate an XML file). It looks like the images did make it over in the import.

On this post, in the browsers web inspector, it shows the source of one of the misfiring images as...

https://i0.wp.com/deephollowfarmct.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/wild-radish-165x300.jpg

...which loads fine on its own, but not in the post itself. So confusing!

Comment: This site is about _development_ with WordPress as software. Support questions about wordpress.com (which is a blogging service) are therefore [off topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Suggesting you try the [support](https://en.support.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows on your new site that it reflects the old domain `http://deephollowfarmct.com/`, if you are not planning to use your domain `http://deephollowfarmct.com/`, you need to re import your xml file to and do a find and replace of the string from `http://deephollowfarmct.com/` to `https://deephollowfarmct.wordpress.com` before importing them.

If you will be using your domain `http://deephollowfarmct.com/` in the wordpress.com site instead of the free tier appending the `wordpress.com` in the URL, I think that should automatically fix your problem

Comment: Ahh... I _think_ that will work. If I wire up the old domain name to this WordPress.com site, everything should snap together... assuming all of the  image paths have been preserved.

Answer (score 1):

I think they locked different domain image access. So, you should have the right permission to access their images or request from image domain owner to give permission for the images. I believe that should works.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: For example, If your site have the images and you don't want to give others domains to access your images. you could make access deny for other domain request. That's how they do. That's why you can't access their images. 

So, when you import the data, check button for download all the attachments.